# DataTables jquery, background color in CSS doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I've tried some solutions, but still it doesn't works.
I'm trying to display data from database in table, using jQuery DataTables plugin.
Technically everything is OK, but the background color of some rows doesn't work.
What's wrong?

```
<html lang="pl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.css">

    <title>Football stats</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#table1').DataTable();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<?php
$polaczenie = new mysqli('localhost','root','','mecze');
$sql = 'MY SELECT';
$wynik = $polaczenie->query($sql);

echo '<body>
<table id="table1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Hour</th>
<th>Country</th>
<th>Team</th>
<th>Ov 2,5</th>
<th>Avg</th>
<th>Ov 1,5ht</th>
<th>LG HT</th>
<th>LG FT</th>
<th>LG</th>
<th>EOver</th>
<th>EAvg</th>
<th>EOvHT</th>
<th>EHt</th>
<th>EFt</th>
<th>ELate</th>
<th>SUMAvg</th>
<th>H2HOver</th>
<th>H2HGAvg</th>
<th>H2HOvHt</th>
</tr>
</thead>';

echo '<tbody>';
while (($rekord=$wynik -> fetch_assoc()) != null)
{
    $explode = explode("/", $rekord['home']);
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['id_match'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['hour'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$explode[2] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$explode[3] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['over'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['goalsavg'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['overht'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['lategoalht'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['lategoalft'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['lategoal'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['EOver'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['EAvg'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['EOvHT'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['EHt'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['EFt'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['ELate'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['SUMAvg'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['H2HOver'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['H2HGAvg'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$rekord['H2HOvHt'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
 echo '</tbody>';
 echo '</table>';
?>
```

There's how it should looks like: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

My rows are not highlited..

Comment: Please remove the server side code which won't run in browser and provide a [mcve] that demonstrates problem

Comment: WIth enough raw html to create table you can put it all in a [stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) and run it right in this page

Comment: Better give a JSFiddle. That gets answers fastest. Or you may want to tag php tag too?

Answer (score 0):

```
<table id="table1" class="stripe" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
```

from [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/stripe.html). If you want on-hover styling you may have to give some javascript. Read more about styling [here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `class="display"` to your table. For example:

```
<table id="table1" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
```

See [styling classes](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes) for more information.